# Best Plugin to Reorder Post Types

Tags: order

I'm looking for a plugin that enables me to reorder pages, posts and custom post types from the normal listing in the WordPress dashboard.

The closest plugin I've found is Simple Page Ordering http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-page-ordering/
however this plugin does not allow post ordering, and also does not easily allow building hierarchies.

So I'm looking for a plugin that does the above but adds support to posts and also enables hierarchies. I like the way the WordPress menu builder lets you add hierarchies by moving a sub page to the right until it attaches itself as a sub-menu.

Another plugin, CMS Tree Page View, does this very well but has its own interface, while I'd prefer using the native interface of WordPress.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used the below plugin and it has worked really well for me:

[Post Types Order](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-types-order/)

It just adds a "Reorder" option in the sub-menu for posts and custom post types and has drag/drop functionality.

Comment: They also have a "Pro" version, which looks like it gives you the ability to create a hierarchy as well:

Comment: Yes I know about that, I would just prefer that there wouldn't be a sub-menu for it. Can't believe it's not already in-built into WordPress. Simple Page Ordering is really close to being perfect.

Comment: when i was looking for similar i think this is the only option available right now.  you know, until you write a new plugin. ;)